# alarm when my host is down

Tags: bash, alert, zenity

I have this bash script which can help me know when some of my servers are down.

```
 #!/bin/bash
HOSTS="192.168.11.154 192.168.11.155"
COUNT=5 

pingtest(){
  for myHost in "$@"
  do
    ping -c "$COUNT" "$myHost" && return 1
  done
  return 0
}

if pingtest $HOSTS
then
  # 100% failed
zenity --warning --text="<span size=\"xx-large\">WARNING</span>\n\n\n<b>*IP*</b> is down" --title="SERVER DOWN" --ok-label="OKAY"
fi
```

so, how can i know what specific server is down? 
I want exchange *IP* to 192.168.11.154 or 192.168.11.155 (depending on what is not available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="192.168.11.154 192.168.11.155"
COUNT=5

pingtest () {
  ping -c "$COUNT" "$1" || return 1
}

for H in $HOSTS; do
  if ! pingtest $H; then
    zenity --warning --text="<span size=\"xx-large\">WARNING</span>\n\n\n<b>${H}</b> is down" --title="SERVER DOWN" --ok-label="OKAY"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Better store ips in two separate variable and call the function twice:-

```
HOSTS1="192.168.11.154"
HOSTS2="192.168.11.155"

if pingtest $HOSTS1
 //

if pingtest $HOSTS2
```